# My dog pees whilst we eat

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

I got a rescue dog from Spain in Aug.. he's great and is toilet trained but he likes to beg and watch us whilst we're eating so I started putting him out in the hall. Problem is he pees in 3/4 different spots in the hall or kitchen. I've even allowed him to stay in the room whilst we eat but he won't go and lie down and stares. I'm not winning either way. Can anyone suggest why he's doing this and what I can do to stop him peeing whilst we're eating.

Comment: Dogs will pee as a sign of submission.  In wolf packs, an omega will sometimes do submissive behavior in order to be allowed to eat by the alphas.  I think this is a possible reason for his behavior.  As for how to stop it, unfortunately, I don't think I'm a person who can give good advice on that.

Answer (score 3):

I think Kai might be right on track here.

When do you feed your dog? Before you're eating? After you're done eating? Or a completely different time?

Try to let the dog stay with you (it should be fine as long as it's not trying to take something on its own). Or is there anything bad about it staring at you? Begging when there might be food is completely normal behavior, you just shouldn't encourage it by giving in too easily.

Then, once you've eaten for a while, get the dog its food as well.

Once that works, you can try to make the timespan longer between you eating and him eating (if you really want to, e.g. to not be disturbed) day after day (don't do it too fast, just 1-2 minutes a day can be enough).